# Postgres - Slow Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having some trouble getting a query to complete execution - it runs and runs and runs and I don't have a deep enough knowledge of indexing and query performance to know how to tweak it to speed up its execution. Query is as follows (it illustrates what I want the end result to be):

```
SELECT
  device.network, device.name AS device, device.mac,
  play.advertiserid, play.filename, play.startdate::timestamp at time zone device.timezone as filestartdate,
  impression.date, impression.views
FROM impression
INNER JOIN device ON
  impression.mac = device.mac
INNER JOIN play ON
  impression.date >= play.startdate::timestamp at time zone device.timezone AND
  impression.date < ((play.startdate::timestamp at time zone device.timezone) + play.spotrunlength * interval '1 second') AND
  play.devicename = device.name
WHERE
  impression.date >= '2017-12-01' AND
  impression.date < '2017-12-31'
ORDER BY impression.date ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

The device table only has about 100 records, but impression and play both have a few million each. I created indexes on all 3 tables that include all of the above columns (including a unique id column in each one), but not sure if there's a better way to approach those indexes, or if there's a much better way to write that query.

Comment: For the purpose of doing joins you want to have the join columns indexed for sure. What I'd do is start with the simplest query possible (e.g. a single table) run it, repeat with the next table joined, and so on. Each time you do this you can see how much the performance degrades and therefore figure out which join could be causing the problem. It would also be helpful if you posted the table schema.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (if the query indeed never finishes, then use only `explain`) [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Pat Jones - it's definitely the play join (as I mentioned - the device table is quite small). I can hit all of those tables individually without issue, because the amount of records being queried is much smaller. Will post the schema shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have access to modify the table structure, but if you do, you can try adding table partitioning (Postgres 10+) on your date columns.  This should speed up any join/search conditions with these tables based on date.

A couple cosmetic things you could try, which probably won't affect the query plan:

1. Use the `BETWEEN` operator for dates: `impression.DATE BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31'`
2. Use a window function like `ROW_NUMBER(OVER ...)` instead of `LIMIT 100`

**Update**
Table partitioning example (from manual):

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
    logdate         date not null,
    peaktemp        int,
    unitsales       int
) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);
```

This will allow you to speed up range queries that specify `logdate`, like `WHERE logdate BETWEEN XXX AND XXX`

More complex example (from manual):

```
CREATE TABLE measurement_year_month (
    logdate         date not null,
    peaktemp        int,
    unitsales       int
) PARTITION BY RANGE (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM logdate), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM logdate));
```

A few links to check out:

Partitioning: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html
CREATE TABLE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: Interesting - I can modify the table structure, but would I still be able to run "normal" queries against the main tables (so if "impression" was broken into a master and children partitions, would I still run selects and updates/inserts against the master)?

Comment: Yes, you can run your "normal" queries.  To set-up partitioning, you use the `PARTITION BY` clause in your `CREATE TABLE` statement.  You'll probably need to re-create the table though.  The way table partitioning works in general is that each row in the table is assigned to a partition within the table based on the partitioning expression specified in the `PARTITION BY`.  That way, your query only has to access a sub-set (partition) of the table when getting rows.  See above for more info.

Comment: Partitioning can only help if the access to `impressions` is a sequential scan, right? Index scans are as fast on big tables as they are on small ones.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  Either way, the less data you have to scan, the quicker your query will be.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that your data model has a problem.

Join conditions like this:

```
impression.date >= play.startdate::timestamp at time zone device.timezone
```

can probably only be processed with a nested loop join, and the condition cannot be indexed well.

Instead of storing local dates and timestamps and manipulating with time zones at query time, you should store all events as `timestamp with time zone`, i.e. as UTC timestamp.

Then your query should become much simpler and can probably use a more efficient hash or merge join.

It is OK to keep time zone information in your data, but use it only for display purposes.

Other than that, make sure that there is an index on `impression.date`.

Comment: Thanks - that's a fair point about the timezone (wasn't sure how to approach that). I'm getting a LOT of crap data from 2 different vendors - one is storing datetimes as epoch values, and the other is storing them in the device's local time (and I just have to know where those devices are, so I added a column locally to store that). I guess it would be better, since I have to add that data anyways, just to convert it while I'm inserting it.

Comment: I'm not blaming you for your data sources, just trying to point out why your query is slow.